# Mount vuejs to DOM element with jQuery

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am making a chrome extension for a specific website and they don't have ID's so I am using jQuery to access the dom element via a complicated query.

When I read the instructions for VueJS it wants me to connect vue to the dom via `el: '#app'` what I am looking for is if I can do something similar to `el: $('#app').find('li').last()`.

Comment: `"el": "#app > li:last-of-type"`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe providing any css selector or html element should resolve this.

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el

> `Type: string | HTMLElement`
>
> Restriction: only respected in instance creation via new.
>
> Details:
>
> Provide the Vue instance an existing DOM element to mount on. It can
> be a CSS selector string or an actual HTMLElement.
>
> After the instance is mounted, the resolved element will be accessible
> as vm.$el.
>
> If this option is available at instantiation, the instance will
> immediately enter compilation; otherwise, the user will have to
> explicitly call vm.$mount() to manually start the compilation.

Therefore if we use the following css selector may be appropriate

```
el: "#app > li:last-of-type"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

`el: $('#app').find('li').last()[0]`

https://jsfiddle.net/3mujL7ac/

But [Denis Tsoi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548793/mount-vuejs-to-dom-element-with-jquery/54548868#54548868) is better.